# Sails.js Model Association Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have been looking at a ton of tutorials and questions here on StackOverflow, but am still stuck.

In Sails.js I am trying to connect two models together that already have data in a MySQL database but I am unable to get Sails to output the data through the association.  I can get Sails to output each of the models independently, but when I try to connect them I just get errors.  I am struggling with getting the association and output linked correctly.

I am trying to output all of the reviews and join the school information to output to a table in a view.

My models are:
api/models/Schools.js

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'mysql',
  tableName: 'schools',
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
    SID: {
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      size: 15
    },
    schoolName: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolCity: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolCountry: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolRegion: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolWebsite: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolCountryCode: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolNumbStudents: {
      type: 'integer',
    },
    schoolNumbFaculty: {
      type: 'integer',
      size: 4,
      defaultsTo: '0'
    },
    schoolCurriculum: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolLanguage: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolLangInstruction: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolonetoone: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolAccred: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolRatio: {
      type: 'string',
      size: 3
    },
    schoolMission: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolFiveWords: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolInitiatives: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolSalaryMin: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolSalaryMax: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolSalaryBA: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolSalaryBAPlus: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolSalaryMA: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolSalaryMAPlus: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolHealth: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolAirfare: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolAirfareProv: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolHousing: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolDependent: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolShipping: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolRetirement: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    reviews: {
      collection: 'review',
      via: 'theschool'
    }
  }
};
```

api/models/Reviews.js

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'mysql',
  tableName: 'reviews',
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
    RID: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      size: 15
    },
    schoolID: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 15
    },
    profileID: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 15
    },
    active: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 1
    },
    dateCreated: {
      type: 'date',
      required: true,
      defaultsTo: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
    },
    Q1: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q2: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q3: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q4: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q5: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q6: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q7: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q8: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q9: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q10: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q11: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q12: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q13: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q14: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q15: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q16: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q17: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q18: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q19: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q20: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q21: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q22: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q23: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q24: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q25: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q26: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q27: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q28: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q29: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q30: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q31: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q32: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q33: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q34: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q35: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q36: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q37: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q38: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q39: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q40: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q41: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q42: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q43: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q44: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q45: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q46: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q47: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q48: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q49: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q50: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q51: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q52: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    freeReview: {
      type: 'text',
      required: true
    },
    theschool: {
      model: 'schools',
      via: 'reviews'
    }
  }
};
```

My controller code is.

```
module.exports = {
  reviews: function(req, res){
    Schools.find().populate('reviews').exec(function afterFind(err, review) {
      if (err) return res.serverError(err);
      console.log(review);
      return res.view({thereviews: review});
    });
  },

};
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am not certain you can use via with the model attribute

Comment: I'm not sure what that means?  If I use the.find() for either one of the models separately I get the data I am looking for.  Isn't the association for connecting two models together?  Or is the issue with the .populate function?

Comment: As you have figured out by yourself, I was saying that in your model definition, in Reviews, for "theschool" attribute you had both "model" and "via". "via" should be used with the type "collection", not with the type "model"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for myself.  For anyone that is stuck...

In Schools.js I amended the model attribute.

```
reviews: {
      collection: 'review',
      via: 'theschool'
    }
```

to

```
 reviews: {
        collection: 'reviews',
        via: 'schoolID',
        dominant: true
    }
```

Where the via references the schoolID in the Reviews.js model

In Reviews.js I amended the model.  I removed the attribute,

```
theschool: {
      model: 'schools',
      via: 'reviews'
}
```

And updated the schoolID attribute to

```
schoolID: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 15,
      model:'schools'
    },
```

Then for the controller I have.

```
reviews: function(req, res){
    Schools.findOne(1)
      .populateAll()
      .exec(function afterFind(err, theresults) {
        if (err) return res.serverError(err);
        return res.view(theresults);
    });
  },
```

It doesn't output the data exactly as I want it, but it is at least connecting the two tables/models together.  I also think the trick is that the via needs to be a table field in the database.